# Can we set collation name while importing data from a CSV file to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The default collation name is "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" when i create a table and import data using CSV file. I just want to set collation name as "Latin1_General_CI_AS" while importing data. Is there any possible way to configure this while importing data itself.

Comment: Define the table columns with the collation you want.

Comment: ALTER TABLE Tablename
  ALTER COLUMN columnname VARCHAR(100)
     COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL -- this consumes more time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Format File` to `Bulk Import` Data.

For example `Format File`:

```
\<?xml version="1.0"?>
\<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  \<FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="7"/>
  \<FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="25" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  \<FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="30" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  \<FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="11"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  \<COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="PersonID" xsi:type="SQLSMALLINT"/>
  \<COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="FirstName" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  \<COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="LastName" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  \<COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="BirthDate" xsi:type="SQLDATE"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

And next, for example `bulk insert` :

```
BULK INSERT dbo.myTable   
   FROM 'D:\BCP\myFile.csv'   
   WITH (FORMATFILE = 'D:\BCP\myFileFormat.fmt');
```